# How to use rpy2 to test significance using a for loop?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pandas, rpy2

I am attempting to run a t-test using r (with the help of the rpy2 package), on some variables from a pandas dataframe. I am using magic functions in jupyter notebook to get python to interact with R. The interaction is successful, except for the loop.

Here is the dataframe:

```
df.head()
Out[60]: 
              ID Category  Num Vert_Horizon Description  Fem_Valence_Mean  \
0  Animals_001_h  Animals    1            h  Dead Stork              2.40   
1  Animals_002_v  Animals    2            v        Lion              6.31   
2  Animals_003_h  Animals    3            h       Snake              5.14   
3  Animals_004_v  Animals    4            v        Wolf              4.55   
4  Animals_005_h  Animals    5            h         Bat              5.29   

   Fem_Valence_SD  Fem_Av/Ap_Mean  Fem_Av/Ap_SD  Arousal_Mean       ...        \
0            1.30            3.03          1.47          6.72       ...         
1            2.19            5.96          2.24          6.69       ...         
2            1.19            5.14          1.75          5.34       ...         
3            1.87            4.82          2.27          6.84       ...         
4            1.56            4.61          1.81          5.50       ...         

   Luminance  Contrast  JPEG_size80   LABL   LABA   LABB  Entropy  \
0     126.05     68.45       263028  51.75  -0.39  16.93     7.86   
1     123.41     32.34       250208  52.39  10.63  30.30     6.71   
2     135.28     59.92       190887  55.45   0.25   4.41     7.83   
3     122.15     75.10       282350  49.84   3.82   1.36     7.69   
4     131.81     59.77       329325  54.26  -0.34  -0.95     7.82   

   Classification  valence_median_split  temp_selection  
0                           Low_Valence             OUT  
1                          High_Valence             NaN  
2                           Low_Valence             OUT  
3                           Low_Valence             OUT  
4                           Low_Valence             OUT  

[5 rows x 35 columns]
```

Here is how I attempted to do it:

```
%Rpush df

Variables = 'All_Valence_Mean', 'Male_Valence_Mean', 'Fem_Valence_Mean'

for var in Variables:
    %R var + '_Sig' <- t.test(var ~ valence_median_split, data = df, var.equal = TRUE)
```

I am attempting to get the results to be saved to the 'var' variable  with a "Sig" string added. This component is not crucial, but what I'm really after is getting this command to recognize "var" as a variable in a list of variables.

Here is the error that I got:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = var ~ valence_median_split, data = df) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'var'

Error in model.frame.default(formula = var ~ valence_median_split, data = df) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'var'

Error in model.frame.default(formula = var ~ valence_median_split, data = df) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'var'
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Error in model.frame.default(formula = var ~ valence_median_split, data = df) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'var'

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
```

Comment: What is `%Rpush df` or `%R`? Is that JuPyter magic calls for `rpy2`? If so, interesting!

Comment: @Parfait yes- those are magic calls for rpy2! I updated the question to clarify. They work well in pushing the df to R, except for this loop. Likely a syntax issue, but not sure where.

Comment: You can't build formulas like that in R, use `as.formula` to convert from string: `vaar <- t.test(as.formula(paste(var, "~ valence_median_split")), data = df, var.equal = TRUE) `

Comment: Do you know of a way to build this in python and then push to R?

Comment: Did you try my above suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are more comfortable with R, push as much of the logical as you can to R. For example, this will store the results in `results`
that you will be able to access from Python in subsequent notebook cells.

```
%%R -i df -o results

Variables <- c("All_Valence_Mean", "Male_Valence_Mean",
               "Fem_Valence_Mean")
results <- list()

for (var in Variables) {
    results[[paste0(var, '_Sig')]] <- t.test(
        as.formula(paste(var, '~ valence_median_split')),
        data = df, var.equal = TRUE)
}
```

If you are more comfortable with Python, keep as much as you can in Python:

```
Variables = ('All_Valence_Mean', 'Male_Valence_Mean',
             'Fem_Valence_Mean')
results = dict()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import Formula
stats = importr('stats')

for var in Variables:
    results[('%s_Sig' % var] = stats.t_test(
        Formula('%s ~ valence_median_split' % var),
        data=df, var_equal=True)
```